# How does ESB differ from Hub/Spoke in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.1

Biztalk supports both Hub/Spoke and ESB(provided as ESB Toolkit). Conventionally Biztalk is used as a Hub/Spoke model where the Biztalk Server acts as a Hub and adapters connecting to the Biztalk Servers acting as a Spoke.

In Terms of typical definition , Hub/Spoke takes care of all the processing load in the Server side whereas in ESB Model the application load is taken care in the connecting applications(Client).

Do the client need to have adapters to communicate to the Biztalk ESB application and does the processing load fall on the client side ?

Answer (score 0):

So, you're reading too much into those terms.

Hub/Spoke & ESB are just patterns you can implement with BizTalk Server, alone with lots of others.  You can use them to describe your app but they're otherwise meaningless.

Also, you don't need the ESBT to make an ESB app and there is no situation I would ever use it.

The answer you specific question, a benefit of using BizTalk Server is to avoid as much change to the endpoints (clients/services) as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyhow I am not able to understand your answer for my core question.

1. If going withe Biztalk ESB, the processing load is going to be on the Server side or the client side?
2. Do the application connecting to the Bus needs to have any specific adapter on the application side ?

Comment: Again, you're over thinking this.  The processing will be wherever you put it, ESB/PubSub/SOA/etc. make no difference.  The BizTalk app should support whatever protocol the client uses.  The goal is to not have to change any client or service endpoint.